# Nuxt Page this.$axios.CancelToken is undefined

Tags: axios, nuxt.js

I'm trying to get an axios module CancelToken generated using the following on a create hook inside a page.

```
created() {
    const source = this.$axios.CancelToken.source()

...
```

But I get

```
TypeError: "this.$axios.CancelToken is undefined"
```

I can't see what I'm doing wrong and the docs appear to be telling me this works.

https://axios.nuxtjs.org/usage#cancel-token

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was due to the nuxtjs/axios package being too old.

The CancelToken only got added in `5.8.0`

https://github.com/nuxt-community/axios-module/releases/tag/v5.8.0